# Install NovaLXD with conjure-up

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

We have been trying to install NovaLXD with conjure-up on localhost on a 18.04. It fails when trying to make network for the Neutron-gateway. For some reason, the container does not bind to any interfaces. The neutron-gateway is named "juju-5bd32c-2" in the attached screenshot [Output of lxc list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wHDX.png). How do we troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: 
In conjure-up, go to advanced settings before deploying. I had to change "eth1" to "eth0" for the node that failed in first attempt, and then deploy again. After this, all containers got IP adresses.